# PayPal donate button inside a form not working

Tags: asp.net, forms, button, paypal

Consider the code below -

```
<form id="Form1" runat=server defaultbutton="cmdclick" style="height: 9%;">

    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XT4SGK2B4H954">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donate_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>

</form>
```

The inner form is not getting submitted. It refreshes the page on clicking on it.
What would be the better method?

Note : Project is in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

An ASPX page is like a giant HTML form and when you throw in another form without closing the ASP one you end up with nested forms.

To resolve the problem you need to close the ASP form before the PayPal button code starts or create a PayPal button as a URL and hyperlink it to some text or an image on your site.

Comment: For your information this page contains form from first till the last

Comment: Yeah, I see that. You can see the nested forms. You would need to close "form id="Form1" runat=server defaultbutton="cmdclick" style="height: 9%;"" before opening the PayPal button form.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that HTML does not allow nested form tags.

Please see my response to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19957382/340045).  I describe an alternative approach to include PayPal buttons in ASP.Net pages.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by adding the paypal code in html page and view it in my asp.net page via iframe.