# ASP.Net - PayPal Buy now button doesn't work

Tags: html, asp.net, paypal

I have a problem with PayPal integration and I couldn't find an answer...
This is my first time working with PayPal so I am doing it simple.

This is the code of the ordinary "Buy now" button

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="TJR2EPBLMHYAL">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="&#1057;&#1091;&#1084;&#1072;">&#1057;&#1091;&#1084;&#1072;</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
    <option value="&#1059;&#1087;&#1083;&#1072;&#1090;&#1080;">&#1059;&#1087;&#1083;&#1072;&#1090;&#1080; $10.00 USD</option>
    <option value="&#1059;&#1087;&#1083;&#1072;&#1090;&#1080;">&#1059;&#1087;&#1083;&#1072;&#1090;&#1080; $20.00 USD</option>
    <option value="&#1059;&#1087;&#1083;&#1072;&#1090;&#1080;">&#1059;&#1087;&#1083;&#1072;&#1090;&#1080; $50.00 USD</option>
    <option value="&#1059;&#1087;&#1083;&#1072;&#1090;&#1080;">&#1059;&#1087;&#1083;&#1072;&#1090;&#1080; $100.00 USD</option>
    <option value="&#1059;&#1087;&#1083;&#1072;&#1090;&#1080;">&#1059;&#1087;&#1083;&#1072;&#1090;&#1080; $200.00 USD</option>
</select> </td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

And I'm geting Error on Sandbox.paypal page
"PayPal cannot process this transaction because of a problem with the seller's website. Please contact the seller directly to resolve this problem."

I'm testing on Localhost.
The button is generated on sandbox seller's account.

Comment: Solved :)
The problem were the Cyrilic letters in the Dropdown list.
They shouldn't be Cyrilic.

Comment: You are using a ASP.net page and you put this form inside it?  If you are interested you might like to read an alternative way of doing [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19957382/340045).